# How to call specific validator instead of calling all the validators in same time by using `form.validate()`?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-form-builder

This is the code :

```
if (form.validate()) {
          // Text forms was validated.
          if (mounted) {
            setState(() {
              _isButtonEnabled = true;
            });
          }
          form.save();
        }
```

I want to call specific validator for specific TextFormField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to wrap each field you want to validate individually with a `Form` Widget and it's own key:

```
class TextFormFieldValidation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TextFormFieldValidationState createState() => _TextFormFieldValidationState();
}

class _TextFormFieldValidationState extends State<TextFormFieldValidation> {
  List<GlobalKey<FormState>> _formKeysList= [
    GlobalKey<FormState>(),
    GlobalKey<FormState>(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Form(
          key: _formKeysList[0],
          child: TextFormField(
            validator: (value) => 'Bad',
          ),
        ),
        Form(
          key: _formKeysList[1],
          child: TextFormField(
            validator: (value) => 'Bad',
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Validate 1'),
          onPressed: () => _formKeysList[0].currentState.validate(),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Validate 2'),
          onPressed: () => _formKeysList[1].currentState.validate(),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Reset'),
          onPressed: () => _formKeysList.forEach((key) => key.currentState.reset()),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @João Soares

Comment: @BlazhenkaParmakova If my answer fixed your issue, please mark it as correct, to help other users. You could also upvote it to improve relevance.

Answer (score 1):

Joao's answer is correct, but it's also over-engineered. You can instead declare a `GlobalKey` for each field that you want to validate independently:

```
GlobalKey<FormFieldState> fieldKey = GlobalKey();
```

Assign it to the `TextFormField` that you want to validate:

```
TextFormField(
    key: fieldKey,
    ...
```

And then use the key to validate that field:

```
bool valid = fieldKey.currentState.validate();
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I couldn't find the FormFieldState on the api documentation. Thank you for the answer.